# Why does the button stay pressed in my code?

Tags: python, tkinter

I really know why mi button stay pressed, the qestion is more like: How can I avoid it? The source code is below, thanks:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd


# creacion de cada venta


# ---ventana 1---
class Window1(tk.Frame):
    final_path = ""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        # inicio y creacion del propio frame
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.config(bg="#33ccff", width='990', height='250')
        # primera etiqueta con valores
        self.label1 = tk.Label(
        self, text="Documento Seleccionado", bg="#33ccff")
        # segunda etiqueta con texto variable
        self.txt_carga = tk.StringVar()
        self.txt_carga.set("Archivo no seleccionado")
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, textvariab=self.txt_carga, bg="#33ccff")

        # primer boton de carga de documentos y funcion del boton
        self.load_button = tk.Button(self, text="Cargar Documento")

        # segundo boton de siguiente
        self.next_button = tk.Button(self, text="Siguiente")

        # Definicion de funciones (Con binding hay que añadir el evento al boton)
        def function_load(event):
            path = fd.askopenfile(filetype=(("Excel", ".xlsx"), ("CSV", ".csv"), ("Todos los Archivos", "*.*")))

            self.final_path = str(path.name)
            self.txt_carga.set(path.name)

        def function_next(event):
            print(self.final_path)

        # binding: de esta manera se llama a las funciones de los botones al final de forma
        # que queda mas ordenado, (x,y) -> x = tipo de evento, y = funcion donde se define
        self.load_button.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', function_load)
        self.next_button.bind('<Button-1>', function_next)
        # instanciacion de los objetos en la ventana
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=200, pady=25)
        self.label2.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=25)
        self.load_button.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20)
        self.next_button.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=20)

# ---ventana inicio------


class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parent = parent
        # necesario para que este se inicie como objeto de la clase Frame
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        # INSANCIAS
        self.window1 = Window1(self)  # instancia de la clase

        self.window1.pack()  # empaquetado de la clase

        self.pack()  # empaquetado propio


# creo el main del programa
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

As you can see my program has a window in which I put a couple of Labels, and a couple of buttons. The problem is caused by the function asigned to the load_button (def function_load), because the filedialog opens but I suppose the process keeps running and that causes the button stay pressed.

Comment: Consider using a Model-View-ViewModel architecture for your program.  See https://github.com/Joklost/tkmvvm.  The code you've posted reminds me of Winforms code from the 1990's, except that Winforms had a visual designer to create this code, and you seem to be writing it from scratch.

Comment: @RobertHarvey. Thank you, I'm relatively new in python programming and in programming in general, it's hard to me to find resources like this by my self. Really thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needn't to bind a event for your button widget if you want to do something when you press them,just set a command for it.And you have a spelling error in your code.Your final code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd


# creacion de cada venta


# ---ventana 1---
class Window1(tk.Frame):
    final_path = ""

    def __init__(self, parent):

        # inicio y creacion del propio frame
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.config(bg="#33ccff", width='990', height='250')
        # primera etiqueta con valores
        self.label1 = tk.Label(
        self, text="Documento Seleccionado", bg="#33ccff")
        # segunda etiqueta con texto variable
        self.txt_carga = tk.StringVar()
        self.txt_carga.set("Archivo no seleccionado")
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.txt_carga, bg="#33ccff") # spelling error.

        # primer boton de carga de documentos y funcion del boton
        self.load_button = tk.Button(self, text="Cargar Documento",command=self.function_load) # add command 

        # segundo boton de siguiente
        self.next_button = tk.Button(self, text="Siguiente",command=self.function_next) # add command 

        # Definicion de funciones (Con binding hay que añadir el evento al boton)

        # binding: de esta manera se llama a las funciones de los botones al final de forma
        # que queda mas ordenado, (x,y) -> x = tipo de evento, y = funcion donde se define
        # instanciacion de los objetos en la ventana
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=200, pady=25)
        self.label2.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=25)
        self.load_button.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20)
        self.next_button.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=20)

    def function_load(self): # it can be a self.function
        path = fd.askopenfilename(filetype=(("Excel", ".xlsx"), ("CSV", ".csv"), ("Todos los Archivos", "*.*")))

        self.txt_carga.set(path)

    def function_next(self):
        print(self.final_path)
# ---ventana inicio------


class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parent = parent
        # necesario para que este se inicie como objeto de la clase Frame
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        # INSANCIAS
        self.window1 = Window1(self)  # instancia de la clase

        self.window1.pack()  # empaquetado de la clase

        self.pack()  # empaquetado propio


# creo el main del programa
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks you for the advice, I have not seen this error.

Comment: @darioperez Yes,maybe your code haven't,but in your post:`self.label2 = tk.Label(self, textvariab=self.txt_carga, bg="#33ccff")`.this has a spelling error.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMAyes, in my code  I have it too. I must improve. Thanks